# Googlebot smartphone redirect

Tags: redirects, googlebot, googlebot-mobile

We are using two different domains for our desktop and mobile websites. 
"www.x.com" and "m.x.com".

The users with mobile devices ending on "www.x.com" are (302) redirected to "m.x.com"

I have just found out when reviewing the Mobile Usability issues in GSC that "Googlebot smartphone" sees the desktop site, even though the alternative links for smaller screens are already defined.

We can easily add 302 redirects for "Googlebot smartphone" but I don't know if it's a wise thing to do. I'm worried that different Google bots will receieve different status messages and content from the same url and no idea about the consequences.

**The question is** 
Shall I do 302 redirects when the user agent is "Googlebot smartphone" while other google bots will remain on the desktop site, or can this actually hurt our ranking?

**Note:** We have already in place 
 - Canonical Urls in mobile website pointing to desktop url
 - Alternative Urls in destop website pointing to mobile urls  << Google seem to ignore this when assessing the usability.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here : https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls

> **Automatic redirection**
>   When a website is configured to serve desktop and mobile browsers using different URLs, webmasters may want to automatically redirect users to the URL that best serves them. **If your website uses automatic redirection, be sure to treat all Googlebots just like any other user-agent and redirect them appropriately.**

Comment: Something similar, we are trying to figure out. 
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128933/is-it-ok-to-have-desktop-url-as-canonical-when-googlebot-is-crawling-as-smartpho